# Let $C_i$ be the cyclic group of order i. Show $C_m \times C_n \cong C_k \times C_l$ where $k \mid l$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $m \leq n$. Show that there exists $k, l$ with $k \mid l$ so that $C_m \times C_n \cong C_k \times C_l$.

What I have tried:

Define $d=gcd(m,n)$ then $m=pd$ and $n=qd$ for some $p,q$. Now I think that $C_m \times C_n$ might be isomorphic to $C_d \times C_{pqd}$.
I know that it's true for $d=1$, because I have proven that $C_m \times C_n \cong C_{mn}$ if $gcd(m,n)=1$.

Comment: What is $C_{m}$? Is that a cyclic group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "I have proven that $C_m \times C_n \cong C_{mn}$ if $\gcd(m,n)=1$", which is good, because we will be using this a lot. But we start by using it in the reverse direction. Let $p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_s^{a_s} = m$ be a prime decomposition of $m$ into distinct primes, and similarily for $q_1^{b_1}\cdots q_t^{b_t} = n$. Now your proven result above, applied $s-1$ and $t-1$ times respectively, gives us
$$
C_m \cong C_{p_1^{a_1}} \times \cdots \times C_{p_s^{a_s}}\\
C_n \cong C_{q_1^{b_1}} \times \cdots \times C_{q_t^{b_t}} 
$$
Collect each prime $p_i$ that does not equal any of the $q_j$, and each $q_i$ that doesn't equal any of the $p_j$, and throw them all, with their respective exponents, into $l$. Finally, for each prime $p_i$ that *does* equal some $q_j$, if $a_i \leq b_j$, throw $p_i^{a_i}$ into $k$ and $q_j^{b_j}$ into $l$, and if $a_i > b_j$, do it the other way around.

Now, for each prime that divides $k$, that prime divides $l$ by at least the same power, so $k \mid l$. Also, if you do the decomposition of $C_k$ and $C_l$ as we did to $C_m$ and $C_n$ above, you will see that in $C_k\times C_l$ and $C_m\times C_n$, all the same factors $C_{p_i^{a_i}}$ and $C_{q_j^{b_j}}$ appear, exactly the same number of times. Therefore, $C_k\times C_l \cong C_m\times C_n$.